# Show me the trajectory

Tags: code-golf, array

Given a list of integers find the "trajectory" that results from indefinitely moving the instructed steps to the right (left if negative), wrapping if necessary, starting at the first element.

A "trajectory", here, is defined as a list containing the elements that are visited only one time, in the order they are visited, and a list containing those visited repeatedly, also in order i.e.:

```
[first, second, ...], [first_of_loop, second_of_loop, ...]
```

Note that:

- Multiple elements may have the same value, yet these are distinct from each other when considering if they have been visited.
- The empty list need not be handled (given an empty list your code may error).

##### Example

Given

```
[6, 0, -6, 2, -9 , 5, 3]
```

we

- start at the first element, the `6`
- step right \$6\$ to the `3`,
- step right \$3\$ to the `-6`,
- step left \$6\$ to the `2`,
- step right \$2\$ to the `5`,
- step right \$5\$ back to the `2`.

Thus the trajectory is

```
[6, 3, -6], [2, 5]
```

...where the second list shows the final loop (we first encounter `2`, then `5`, then loop forever).

##### Test Cases

```
                                  in  out
                                 [0]  [], [0]
                                 [3]  [], [3]
                             [-1, 2]  [-1], [2]
               [5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 3, 1]  [], [5, 3, 2, 6, 4, 1]
             [6, 0, -6, 2, -9 ,5 ,3]  [6, 3, -6], [2, 5]
              [4, 5, 2, 6, -2, 7, 8]  [4], [-2, 2]
           [6, 10, 10, 0, -9, -4, 6]  [6, 6], [-4, 10, -9, 10]
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]  [], [9, 9, 9, 9]
```

Comment: Can we output two lists `[a, b]` where `a` has the elements visited, and `b` the loop?

Comment: May I ask why such a restrictive output format?

Comment: @Dudecoinheringaahing Hmm, I think I'll reconsider. Will edit in to allow `visited once, in order` and `loop in order` separately.

Comment: The output format is impossible in many strictly typed languages.

Comment: @pxeger ... see ^

Comment: @Bubbler addressed.

Comment: Can we output the two lists in the opposite order (ie the loop first)?

Comment: @NickKennedy yes, since there are two outputs they may be in either order; just specify so in your answer.

Comment: Can we omit the first list in output if it's empty?

Comment: @pajonk, although that would be unambiguous (since the second list is never empty), I'm going to say that the empty list is part of the "trajectory" and require it to always be produced.

Answer (score 7):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library), <s>61</s> <s>60</s> 58 bytes

```haskell
(i:y)#x|i?>y=m(x!)&@sp(/=i)(rv y)|u<-(i+x!i)%l x:i:y=u#x
([0]#)
```

[hgl](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library) is an experimental golfing library I am developing for Haskell.  I started a few days ago and this is my first answer, and it's proof there is still a lot of room for improvement.

From this post I've learned that:

- I should probably make a dedicated function for `m.(!)`, since it is likely to come up more than just here.
- I need versions of `sp` (`span`) and `bk` (`break`) that include the element that matches / doesn't match the predicate in the first part.  I had to use a hack with `rv`, which is costly and only works in this specific scenario.
- <s>I should make an infix version of `e` (`elem`).  It would have saved me at least a byte here.</s>  Turns out I had already done this (`(?>)`).  Maybe what I actually need is better documentation that makes it easier to find this stuff.
- <s>I should make an infix version of `jB`.  It would have saved me at least 2 bytes here.</s> This also existed and I didn't realize (`(&@)`). There might be a pattern here.
- It might be a good idea to make an infix of `sp`. It could have saved me a byte here if I hadn't made an infix of `jB`.
- I have probably overall underestimated the usefulness of infixes and I should in general just make more of them.

#### But here's how it actually works:

Vocab:

- `(?>)`: checks if a list contains an element (`elem`)
- `m`: map (`fmap`)
- `(!)`: index a list (sort of `(!!)`)
- `(&@)`: maps function across both parts of a tuple.
- `sp`: splits a list at the first element that matches a predicate (`span`)
- `rv`: reverses a list (`reverse`)
- `(%)`: modulo infix (`mod`, yes Haskell does not have a modulo infix)

So this builds up a list of indices, when a index is added that is already in the list it stops and splits at the last occurrence of that index, and converts the indices to their values.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>53</sup> 48 bytes

*-5 thanks to Jonah!*

```
(_2{.{~</.~]+./\@e.r)(]~.@,r=.(#@[|]+{~){:)^:_&0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY4xC8IwEIX3/oqHgmlojWlao00tFAQnJ1etGaStuAhdI/nrMRWii9wdPN777riHmzHSo1YgSMGh/CwZ9qfjwcVaGGbsbsVsm7DVpenYSOPWsiYdaxbPm/OrTYylRtGr0gvuaDR4vyKKVD2Nutv9iQE8iDwInUEEvYZAAYkNcmTBlP4JLX2iSw9894oPLaGFx7c/OONT84nW/lYIyv8VuTc)

- `r=.(#@[|]+{~){:` take the last index (starting with 0 `&0`), get the corresponding value, add it to the index and take the mod.
- `]~.@, … ^:_` append the new value to the indices list and repeat that process until the list does not change after removing duplicates
- `]+./\@e.r` the next index is a duplicate, so we find it in the indices list and have a bitmask: 0 for visited once, 1 for loops.
- `_2{.{~</.~` group the values based on the indices. Because there might be no items that are visited once, we can pad the output with taking the last two items `_2{.`

Another approach would be to not build a list, but just repeat the index-shift-mod-loop `<@#` times, keeping the results, and then search for the loop. But I didn't get it shorter than this.

Comment: 51 bytes with `</.` with after all: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY4xC8IwEIX3/opDwSS0XtO0RptaKAhOTq61ZpC24iJ0jeSvx1SILnJ38Lj3veMeboFkgFoBgQQ4KD9rhMP5dHRaGGypsfsUbRdjeml6nBjtLDbJVCOly6Z9dbGxzCjGrkqvuGPR6J2KKFINLOpv9yeMwIPIg9AZiKA3IKAACVvIIQtL6f/Q0ju69MA3V3xoCVp4fPeDMz43n2ntbwWj/F@RewM "J – Try It Online")

Comment: Here's my alternative 53 byte solution. Maybe you can see a way to get it below 51: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVFNa8MwDL3nV4jmkGSTXdv52BpSCAx22mlXz8thtKw7rJcOBin565nsxNBsAzdERnnvyVKePsYVT/awrSEBBAE1BePw8Pz0OHaq5yZN@2HgWbPmg2xkzLetyeKzuF2/tCj6lUx7fuYme61T1bQ3cTZm0e7t/Qh7ED7JfdJJUD4vERRCgVAh3CHkCNJThAiErnKKbkNzkTi/YKWYwqo2FPaWiSaegMAb7b4PpySJIPgcPgGOX6ewUgtDh0GbXKHOvToPqDWT5IJxidWrP3r9j5H@9tJ9KkcVFl8W68loNhnNyOgS0I1WuUJWuZZk/@@uusB5gaRkyjW@t4WFrbDAclC9XBqjLTA78dzL9bGAnElJLurwIv1/XiDjDw "J – Try It Online")

Comment: @Jonah Right, there can't be an output with only visited-once but no loops. Clever `_2{.` trick!

Comment: New 51 byte version of alternative method: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVFNa4NAEL37K4Z4UJvZdT/UNmIhUOipp1631kNIaHpoLikUDP51O7u6ENvCVpxlfO/NzvjmfVzx5AD3NSSAIKCmYBwenp8ex7RTPU/7YeBZk/NBNm2c8zaLL2Kdv2xR9CuZ9vxC0GudqmZ7E2djFu13byc4gPCJ9kknQfm8RFAIBUKFcIugEaSnCBEIXeUU3YamIrG@YqWYwqo2FPaWiSaegMAb7b@O5ySJIPgcPwBOn@ew0oiWjhZt8g@19modUBsmyYXWJVavfunNH0b620v3qRxVWHxZbCaj2WQ0I6NLQDda5QpZ5VqS/T@7mgLnBZKSKdf4zhYWtsICy0HNcmmMtsDsxHMv18cCciYluWjCi/T/eYWM3w "J – Try It Online") (I can almost _taste_ 49!)

Comment: 48 removing extra parens from yours! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY4xC8IwEIX3/oqHgmlojWlao00tFAQnJ1etGaStuAhdI/nrMRWii9wdPN777riHmzHSo1YgSMGh/CwZ9qfjwcVaGGbsbsVsm7DVpenYSOPWsiYdaxbPm/OrTYylRtGr0gvuaDR4vyKKVD2Nutv9iQE8iDwInUEEvYZAAYkNcmTBlP4JLX2iSw9894oPLaGFx7c/OONT84nW/lYIyv8VuTc "J – Try It Online")

Comment: @Jonah Huh, didn't know assignment breaks up trains. TIL, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 92 bytes

```javascript
a=>[(g=p=>a=1/(i=g[p%=w=a.length])?[]:[q=a[p],...g(p+q+w*q*q,g[p]=k++)])(k=0).splice(0,i),a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVHbboQgEH3vV8xLE1gHFG/tNmH7IYQHYl1r1yjWTffzLdDamDTRLGEe5sycM2fgw3yZqfps7ZX1w1s9n@Vs5EmRRlp5MlLEpJWNso/yJg3v6r65vmv6qvSLGqVRViPnvCE2GqPbYTyM6Hq1vEQR1ZRcZEL5ZLu2qkmCLUWj52rop6GreTc05Exg76hEUwpxDEqjTx7u5WdrfnYXXzGBkC58JrxCuqOgCkdByBFKhCeEDEGsHRQBSkM597UtOeWaEgRWBgY7AhaAfwuVQYqVwRZCse1MuWnFMpmlwdzzIpV7DQ9urecHiuQnvKujC7/nyk/w4kHx2yD@/Zhy6M5dv9cKnb8B)

#### Commented

```javascript
a => [                 // a[] = input array
  ( g = p =>           // g is a recursive function taking a position p
                       // the underlying object of g is also used to keep
                       // track of the positions that are visited
    a =                // update a[]
      1 / (            //
        i = g[         // reduce the position modulo the length w of the
          p %= w =     // array and load g[p] into i
            a.length   //
        ]              //
      ) ?              // if i is defined:
        []             //   we've found the loop: stop the recursion
      :                // else:
        [              //   update the output array:
          q = a[p],    //     load a[p] into q
          ...g(        //     do a recursive call:
            p + q +    //       add q to p
            w * q * q, //       also add w*q² to make sure it's >= 0
            g[p] = k++ //       save the index k into g[p] and increment k
          )            //     end of recursive call
        ]              //   end of array update
  )(k = 0)             // initial call to g with p = k = 0
  .splice(0, i),       // extract the non-looping part
  a                    // append the looping part
]                      //
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) -xp, 32 bytes

```
^:iT(Yy+a@y%:#a)NiiPBya@i^@:i@?y
```

Takes the list (formatted like so: `[1;2;-3]`) as a command-line argument, and outputs a list of two lists. [Try it here!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip) Or, [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##K8gs@F8dZpVoHe7@P84qM0QjslI70aFS1Uo5UdMvMzPAqTLRITPOwSrTwb7yf62Cr0L6/2iDWK5oYyDWNbRWMALSpkDKWsHEWsHMWsHcWsHYWsEQKArkGFgr6JqBJXUtrRVMFaxBuoDqIBqAMrpGYB0WEOWGBhBsAFGvCzIRKANkEkCx/3WLAgA) at TIO.

#### Explanation

```
^:iT(Yy+a@y%:#a)NiiPBya@i^@:i@?y
                                  a is cmdline input, eval'd (-x flag);
                                  i is 0, y is "" (implicit)
^:i                               Split i and assign back to i: i is now [0]
   T                              Loop until
      y                            current index
       +a@y                        plus number at current index
           %:                      mod
             #a                    length of list
     Y                             (yank into y, making this the new index)
    (          )Ni                 is already in the list of indices traversed:
                  iPBy              Push the new index onto the list of indices
                                  After the loop, we have the list of unique
                                  indices traversed in i and the first repeated
                                  index in y
                      a@i         Values from a at each index in i
                         ^@:      split at
                            i@?y  the index of y in i
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 42 bytes

```
≔⁰ζＷ¬№υζ«⊞υζ≔﹪⁺ζ§θζＬθζ»≔⌕υζζＵＭυ§θιＩ⟦…υζ✂υζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/NCsIwEITP9ily3EIKoihITyUgCFYKHksPoQ1NIE20SfzFZ4@pUfC0OzP7Lbstp2OrqfS@MEb0CuYYPdI8uXIhGYKDtkC0Uxbc5KcpeiazyhkedZ7MvlipOyc1VNIZeGBU2J3q2A3OHwqjPVO95XCe@gl7JV9uK1QXd8WgpCeih4FG92@NSENajSKcQqixUJN7Kxnh@vTDj1K0LIomDHtf12uMwj9ZKItQNhitMFo2jc8u8g0) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⁰ζ
```

Start at index 0.

```
Ｗ¬№υζ«
```

Repeat until a duplicate index is found.

```
⊞υζ
```

Save the current index.

```
≔﹪⁺ζ§θζＬθζ
```

Calculate the new index.

```
»≔⌕υζζ
```

Find the position of the repeat.

```
ＵＭυ§θι
```

Replace the indices with the values.

```
Ｉ⟦…υζ✂υζ
```

Output the values before and after the repeat as separate arrays.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 91 bytes

```ruby
->l{*r=a=b=0;r<<a until b=r.index(a=(a+l[a])%l.size);[z=r[0,b],r-z].map{|x|l.values_at *x}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcXRCoIwFADQX7kvgdrdGEVB6O1Hxog7miAskeliTf325Xk5Idpf6amIp1@bQEyWVBu6jiGOy@DBUpDD@HapYqr47DWb@uTlPGRXtzpT0AqtwSCykR@e1i1tXn7ZRze/eIEm7XuZoAet7wgKQRxdjh6AcEO4GlP@)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 137 bytes

```c
a,i,j;
#define f(l,z){int t[z]={i=j=0},h[z];for(;!(a=t[i]);i=(z+i+l[i]%z)%z)h[j]=l[i],t[i]=++j;for(i=0;i<j;)printf("! %d"+!!--a,h[i++]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZHtaoMwFIb/exXRUVA8oUn8mmS5kpAf0tU10rnSOhgWr92dpMWu3WAayDnvefKefGzoZt/0b/PcgIVOBk@v29b2W9LGexiTs@0HMujRqLNVnWIT7DCR7ccxlmHcqEFbk0ir4jG16R6T1Zjg2OnOKJeCA1Sadn6JVUzal04mhyP6tnEUktVrlIYhpQ0a2zRFs2l2Pd8b25M4OQfE72B7GjTuoQTCgFCcBE41AVIAySZ5pZhj2JJyl96qwqWUg1iUzCmFN8uBoGuFbkD4AhQOyH0X4QEqPPS8EOV1W5wBDga0BppDudQrV6@B/DOQD/DKB3RJDp/DKY6iRHqF/1IEiAclg@qmrNegC8hAQAk5cOMJvL@fjNeK@1U6N0C0O6C4rCkf6iWUBjSejvtjcnbBKuDivnsN/jfBNOu/X8wErsCBuOtG4QsjF2JnzVzs8cxF@OEDcPMN)

```
l : list , z : length 
int t[z] : kinda sieve, every step sets the visited item to step number
h[z] : save the trajectory values in order for output
for(;!(a=t[i]) : we iterate until we find a visited item, saving in a the first already visited
;i=(z+i+l[i]%z)%z) : modulo hack 

at each iteration :
h[j]=l[i] : add item to output list
,t[i]=++j; : and update sieve

Output
for(i=0;i<j;) : j is the number of items visited
printf("! %d"+!!--a,h[i++]) 
a is the beginning of loop so we 
put a separator by including '!' in format string
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>32</s> <s>29</s> <s>25</s> 23 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to Razetime*

```
†!¹G-§eoUṠ-UUm←¡Sṙo!¹←ŀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HDAsVDO911Dy1PzQ99uHOBbmho7qO2CYcWBj/cOTMfKAXkHG34//9/tJmOgY6umY6Rjq6ljqmOcSwA)

Outputs loop first, then first-visited.

**Piece by piece:**

Make an infinite list of lists of indices by repeatedly shifting by the input value indexed by the first element:

```
¡Sṙo!¹←ŀ
```

And get the first element of each of these: this is the list of indices:

```
m←
```

Now, get the longest non-repeating prefix (this includes one copy of the repeating elements):

```
U
```

And get the repeating indices:

```
oUṠ-U
```

Join these together into a list of 2 lists:

```
§e
```

And remove the first (the repeating indices) from the second (the prefix):

```
G-
```

Finally, use these to index into the original input:

```
†!¹
```

Comment: I was trying to find a way to use span but `Sȯ↕≠→hḟS≠uḣm←¡Sṙ←` is wrong since it's not considering indices. Was thinking there would be a better way to do this.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HDAsVDO91Sg0@sf9Q29VHngkdtkzIe7pgfDGSWPtyxOPdR24RDC4Mf7pyZD1QH5Bxt@P//f7SlDlYYCwA "Husk – Try It Online") annoyingly 1 byte longer.

Comment: @Razetime - you should still post it.  The ```Sȯ↕≠→hḟS≠u``` approach is really nice.

Comment: @Razetime - and, stealing your ```¡Sṙo!¹←ŀ``` trick, we can get to [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HDAsVDO911Dy1PzQ99uHOBbmho7qO2CYcWBj/cOTMfKAXkHG34//9/tJmOgY6umY6Rjq6ljqmOcSwA)...

Comment: neat, add it in.

Comment: @Razetime - done (with credit).  Note that your version could have been only [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/PzdX8dDO4BPrH7VNfdS54FHbpIyHO@YHA5mlD3cszn3UNuHQwuCHO2fmA1UBOUcb/v//H22pgxXGAgA) by dropping ```Fe``` and using ```mm``` instead of ```†```...

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 116 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,i=0,k=[]:i in k and[[a[q]for q in x]for x in[k[:k.index(i)],k[k.index(i):]]]or f(a,(i+a[i])%len(a),k+[i])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZBNb4JAEIbP@ismJk1262D4EFpJOFkOXhrT2KbJZg9rxLgBESm29tfTna3EfhwgLDvz7DvzDlt9NrtDGbTtNinUfr1RoFAnLuaJkLEGXUIOqtwIocRRbg81HImdbXg2ochFnE90ucnOTHOJubhmsZTSyLZMIdNjJbTkN0VWMsUxH1PWfux0kcGqPmXxcKAQ1pDAXlUse1cFmu7VqWF88tbUuqK9KnTDRgAjzoeDqtalyRaPy@dVPEJQV5a@LtP5Kn0gfLu@8qd0ni5eLtyMxXkLfY9wpflIpGDYrw46ddCjFo6H4EsbkN7/pxehESBMESKEO4QAweu6hzb17dGU@O9iYbCL4ERW48wAQ0A7WmQLnchaIoR/XYXpFnadHd8a31PhlCoI/B6UGnru9yLHmVk08cXL@hDwLoeeuUVh9p63@88f5As)

Comment: Save four with a walrus: `...for x in[k[:(z:=k.index(i))],k[z:]]]`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan tried that, but you can't use those in list comprehensions

Comment: Oh, I forgot that; ah well.

Comment: [113 bytes](https://tio.run/##RYzBCsIwEER/ZS9ColspFgUD/ZJlD5E0uM2altJD/PoYvXh6b4Zh1vf@XPJQaxzVvx7Bg6KMPR6TE5AMCXwOREqF47JB@XbzT@emlMils@QwFSOWMdE/OWZus2gUjZyUhO1Bp2zUtnMUW9dN8m6ioRtCj9A1XBrugHBFGNja@gE)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>121</s> <s>118</s> <s>108</s> <s>102</s> <s>101</s> 99 bytes

*-10 bytes and another -6 thanks to [@Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)*

```r
function(a,t=1){while(!(t=(t+a[t]-1)%%sum(a|1)+1)%in%T)T=c(T,t)
split(a[T],cut(cumsum(T==t),-1:1))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/?fbclid=IwAR1DVml-S6X2G9FaLKvkNJy0r39FC1Pqq2Fi0Lp4mvQZ1e1Megiil4wdFSM##hY3NCoMwDMfvPkV3EBJMwfqxzUHfojfxIGUyQd2YKTtse3bXqvdBvn//JM@l00vnJsv9fYKWWCt8v279cIUDsAZO2pobqTCOZzdC@1GY@KafYoNGWzDEGM2PoWdoa9OQdQzWjUFrtGYkqS4K8bt0YOFIIiUhfcp8qgSJkkSOGHWQhiDzEC1IRRluZblqCxJ@6eTFJNROinU7W4nMVnrekZ@odPPwr/IeLuzUt38McfkB)

The outputted lists have weird names (two intervals), but it I hope it's ok.

Comment: Great!  My best attempt was much, much worse than this!  Well done.  I think you can even [save a handful more bytes](https://tio.run/?fbclid=IwAR1DVml-S6X2G9FaLKvkNJy0r39FC1Pqq2Fi0Lp4mvQZ1e1Megiil4wdFSM##hY3NDoIwDMfvPMU8kLShSxiKirorT7Ab2WEhEmCKiWA8IM@OG3I3aftv@@vHc67kXL26cmgeHRiycpxwfNfN7QobFTZdaHG0RX7heSS0VGclQUWmiJTmAsOwf93BfARGYgpuTT@AKWzBoZV3M5Q1KLJ4ylFr8v1Wa5zmCkrYE4uJcSeJk4wRS4ltEYMKYh/41scSuKAEf2m6zO6IuaWDGyYmVrJbtpOF8GShxxW5joh/7v9lzv2FlbryjyHOXw), and one more by reversing the output...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen, thanks! I was trying to make it work with `T` and also tried negative indexing, but with no success. Should have tried more...

Comment: [Some more byte-savings](https://tio.run/?fbclid=IwAR1DVml-S6X2G9FaLKvkNJy0r39FC1Pqq2Fi0Lp4mvQZ1e1Megiil4wdFSM##hY3NCoMwDMfvPkU9CAmmYKtuE9a36E16kDKZog5mZYdtz@5a9T7I9@@f5Lm2am2XybruMUFDTgl8v@7dcIMYnAKXNrUzXGCSzMsIzUdg6ptuSjRqZUGTw2joZgdNrev@ymO7jEGplXJoDIVx3BuD37UFCydiGTHuk/SpYsRKYjli1EIWAs9DtMAFSdzLctMWxPzS2YuJiYMU27bcCJcbvRzIT0S2e/hXeQ8XDurbP4a4/gA)...  (and output no longer reversed).

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 26 bytes

```
L‘0ị+ị¥%L}ɗƬɗƬ%LḊḣ2fQ,ḟʋ/ị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/nUcMMg4e7u7WB@NBSVZ/ak9OPrQFhVZ@HO7oe7lhslBao83DH/FPd@kAV/w@3P9y5T4XrcPujpjWR//9Hc0UbxOpwRRuDCF1DHQUjEMMUSOsomOgomOkomOsoGOsoGIKEgTwDHQVdM7CsrqWOAlAdWKMJmGkEVq9rBNZjAdVgaADBBhAduiBDQVJANgEUyxULAA)

A monadic link taking a list of integers and returning two lists of integers, with the looped integers first.

Comment: Nice, and different to mine... I'll post it shortly.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>23</s>  22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/iki/Code-page)

Quite possibly still beatable...

```
ĖUṙFḢƊƬḢ€⁺JœṖ€$§ṪọɗƇLṪ
```

A monadic Link that accepts the list and yields a list of lists.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///ItNCHO2e6Pdyx6FjXsTVA6lHTmkeNu7yOTn64cxqQrXJo@cOdqx7u7j05/Vi7D5D5/3A7UPjopIc7ZwDpyP//o6MNYrl0oo1BhK6hjoIRiGEKpHUUTHQUzHQUzHUUjHUUDEHCQJ6BjoKuGVhW11JBx1RBB6wRqBKiBSilawTWYwHVYGgAwSCNlkAMMhQkBWQTQLFcsQA)**

#### How?

```
ĖUṙFḢƊƬḢ€⁺JœṖ€$§ṪọɗƇLṪ - Link: list of integers A=[a,b,...,x,y,...]
Ė                      - enumerate -> [[1,a],[2,b],...,[n,x],[m,y],...]
 U                     - upend     -> [[a,1],[b,2],...,[x,n],[y,m],...]
      Ƭ                - collect until a repeat under:
     Ɗ                 -   last three links as a monad, f(current=[[x,n],[y,m],...]):
   F                   -   flatten (current) -> [x,n,y,m,...]
  ṙ                    -   rotate (current) left by (each of [x,n,y,m,...])
    Ḣ                  -   head -> rotation by x
       Ḣ€              - head each -> leftmost of each, [[a,1],...,[x,n],...]
         ⁺             - repeat Ḣ€ -> visited elements in order, [a,...,x,...,last_of_loop]
              $        - last two links as a monad, f(V=[a,...,x,...,last_of_loop]):
          J            -   range of length -> [1,2,...,length(V)]
           œṖ€         -   partition (V) before each (of those) indices
                   Ƈ   - filter (all of these 2-partitions) keeping if:
                    L  -   use length (of A) on the right of...
                  ɗ    -   last three links as a dyad, f(partition, length(A)):
               §       -     sums
                Ṫ      -     tail -> length of the potential loop
                 ọ     -     how many times is that divisible by length(A)?
                             (positive (truthy) if an actual loop, else 0 (falsey))
                     Ṫ - tail
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 22 bytes

```
0¸Δ¤DIsè+Ig%©ªÙ}D®QÅ¡è
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4NCOc1MOLXHxLD68QtszXfXQykOrDs@sdTm0LvBw66GFh1f8/x9tpqNgaADBQKRrCcQmOgpmsQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>156</s> 145 bytes

```powershell
for($v=@();!(($s=$v.IndexOf($i))+1);$i%=$l){$v+=,+$i
$t+=,($u=$args[+$i])
$i+=$u+($l=$args.Count)}if(--$l*$s){$t[$s..$l],$t[0..--$s]}else{$t,@()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZJfa9swFMXf9Snuwt0qzZLrP4m3EASG0sGeWtbHEIbnyquHWmeWnXVk/uzZlZ0mfRhDxtx7zu@eK7C3zS/TugdjrSqb1hyw0vtD1bQcdzrnYvWGc3Qad@Hnp3vzfFNxrIUIYrHC@q1GK/a4C7QMsGbYUcGx11i0392apI1gWAca@4CjneTwqumfOjHUFVcK7Xt0lNCt0YUh2o2kMgpDctxmMNYZ8iTdYjgMjOWcMWou4BKiCwkRiJc2pTbnqTgqKiYtIU3FMjlTC0ghgQzmEJO3kImcy0x@kKmMj1BGhMr8MCwIyWQkVUacWsqFTI/QnHyVjPlz6VMyqRKK@XgK8QmKtkSglvQek@LIP5GPUrT2fKvldAhayn8eQpmAP/Cpaa@L8kHdfPthyg72jAGged5SY@4loK1dBxrwq9dt02xJ69rCw037m5x3WEHuKT@5vr276l3XPE5xm3xPIsBdX5bGOV9qmL2ev5xCZ6DMz/Pe1Th1W7TFo@noPxqntqd2NvlfjOttB/9JnbjrY@rInXaQRV9/YIe/)

Takes a list as parameter.

Returns two lists: loop first then trajectory

Saved:

- 2 bytes by swapping the loop / trajectory in the result
- 2 bytes by reusing `$args[$i]` as `$u`
- 1 byte by merging the declaration and first usage of `$l`
- 3 bytes by not initialising `$i` anymore
- 3 bytes thanks to *mazzy*!

##### Not golfed:

```powershell
$index = 0
$length = $args.Count
for ($indices = @(); ($truncateAt = $indices.IndexOf($index)) -eq -1) {
    $indices += , $index
    $trajectory += , $args[$index]
    $index = ($index + $args[$index] + $length) % $length
}
if (--$length -and $truncateAt) {
    ($trajectory[0..--$truncateAt] -join ','), ($trajectory[++$truncateAt..$length] -join ',')
}
else {
    '', ($trajectory -join ',')
}
```

Comment: [`--$l-*$s`?](https://tio.run/##fZJfa9swFMXf9Snuwt0qzZLrP4m3EASG0sGeWtbHEIbnyquHWmeWnXVk/uzZlZ0mfRhDxtx7zu@eK7C3zS/TugdjrSqb1hyw0vtD1bQcdzrnYvWGc3Qad@Hnp3vzfFNxrIUIYrHC@q1GK/a4C7QMsGbYUcGx11i0392apI1gWAca@4CjneTwqumfOjHUFVcK7Xt0lNCt0YUh2o2kMgpDctxmMNYZ8iTdYjgMjOWcMWou4BKiCwkRiJc2pTbnqTgqKiYtIU3FMjlTC0ghgQzmEJO3kImcy0x@kKmMj1BGhMr8MCwIyWQkVUacWsqFTI/QnHyVjPlz6VMyqRKK@XgK8QmKtkSglvQek@LIP5GPUrT2fKvldAhayn8eQpmAP/Cpaa@L8kHdfPthyg72jAGged5SY@4loK1dBxrwq9dt02xJ69rCw037m5x3WEHuKT@5vr276l3XPE5xm3xPIsBdX5bGOV9qmL2ev5xCZ6DMz/Pe1Th1W7TFo@noPxqntqd2NvlfjOttB/9JnbjrY@rInXaQRV9/YIe/ "PowerShell Core")

Answer (score 2):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 146 bytes

```
length as$l|def x:((.[0]+.[1][-1])%$l+$l)%$l;def n:x as$x|.[1]|index($x);. as$i|[0,[],[]]|until(n;[$i[x],.[1]+[x],.[2]+[$i[x]]])|.[2][:n],.[2][n:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hU3basMwDH3vV@jBg4TIIU7Xbk0@ReihtGnnYdyNZuAHf/s8Kf6AgQ46Ohf787tQCUu8rx9wfpqQr8sN0tQ0PQ3c9eSYrOP2xYTOBF2zBuKUNJ2yBrKP1yU1JrVzr6rPNCCxDOefuPrQxJmMp8So8a6SUcgmMrdZT5pi1SlOXLjI/zvaC6xDGGUfZCG8IhwR3hD2CE5UOQYEe9xMewI8AGpLcrUgjh23xnuNu6FCayeBviiO0H@Gd7@Pr9U/4rPYyx8)

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 39 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
↕∘≠⊸{⊏⟜¨2↑⊒⊸/⊸(+`⊑⊸=)⊸⊔0∾⊑˜⍟⟜⊑≠⊸|+}
```

[Try it here](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oaV4oiY4omg4oq4e+KKj+KfnPCdlanCqDLihpHiipLiirgv4oq4KCtg4oqR4oq4PSniirjiipQw4oi+4oqRy5zijZ/wnZWo4p+c4oqR4omg4oq4fPCdlagr8J2VqX0KCkbCqOKfqDDin6nigL/in6gz4p+p4oC/4p+owq8xLCAy4p+p4oC/4p+oNSwgMiwgNCwgNiwgNywgMywgMeKfqeKAv+KfqDYsIDAsIMKvNiwgMiwgwq85ICw1ICwz4p+p4oC/4p+oNCwgNSwgMiwgNiwgwq8yLCA3LCA44p+p4oC/4p+oNiwgMTAsIDEwLCAwLCDCrzksIMKvNCwgNuKfqeKAv+KfqDksIDksIDksIDksIDksIDksIDksIDksIDksIDksIDksIDnin6kK).

```
↕∘≠⊸{⊏⟜¨2↑⊒⊸/⊸(+`⊑⊸=)⊸⊔0∾⊑˜⍟⟜⊑≠⊸|+} #  is input,  is indices 0,1,..,length-1
↕∘≠⊸{                                 } # pass indices into the main function as 
                                ≠⊸|+  # add indices to the input mod the length
                          ⊑˜⍟⟜⊑        # traverse from the first element a number
                                        #  of steps equal to the length,
                                        #  accumulating results
                        0∾              # prepend 0
           ⊒⊸/⊸(+`⊑⊸=)⊸⊔                # find the first value to repeat and
                                        #  partition by occurrences
         2↑                             # take the first 2 groups
     ⊏⟜¨                               # and use them to index into the input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>115</s> 131 bytes

```c
f(r,n,o,l,j)int*r,**o,*l;{int*t=malloc(4*n);for(*l=j=0;j+=o[0][(t[j]=++*l)-1]=r[j],!t[j=(j%n+n)%n];);*l-=l[1]=t[j]-1;o[1]=*o+l[1];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZHbbtswDIavq6dgDWSQZGmwnDRtp/lJDF0Enj3IUKVAcYFiRZ49I@UMS7dhPgAk9ZH8SQ36@zBcLhPPKqqkgpqFj4vMSsqkZLDv5C3dyyGENPCdjMJOKXMZurlr7Fx3qW9cz5d@dl1dyyC0cV1GT91jrOPzJtZRbKKzwsqgu9DjOdHa2ES2TDXF7PlyzNjrkDOnloCGArQgjFG8s7tyOvGqr4Rld6gBiAOPKvxXZKyvawG/qM23jfx8qhRW6b1TvjbEqApK9vF1OfHKkX1mLwcfOXagatGy03CIpUClPuGwjKa1ELW2AlAGUdJHBUGB5Ol16VsnFIlEA0vfpgfq5SN0cF1fkCf/Y0wTKRd0SPmN@w/w55zrlDdNcEW1LyS/qsKaRU8Z9LoOwMfHLzT9zZYVhSHcgsc8Tv7tI7iKXGc07mPZkNLxb9pc6cb93vZ6bXkcsbGwUKy1crmF8@WJGdbgv2Ut0wZa9sgeoIUd7OERtmDQ30MDeo9B/QwPsMXIDojZg24ReiqIaehriNGYzEzLnuGf708)

Outputs `[prefix, loop]` into `o` and `[len(loop), len(prefix)]` into `l`. Expects these to have allocated enough memory to fit the output (though `o[1]` is discarded).